# Is there any way to add a new location to the list of places where nltk looks for the wordnet corpus?

Tags: python, ubuntu, nltk

I can't use the nltk wordnet lemmatizer because I can't download the wordnet corpus on my university computer due to access rights issues.

I get the following error when I try to do so:

```
**********************************************************************   Resource 'corpora/wordnet' not found.  Please use the NLTK   Downloader to obtain the resource:  >>> nltk.download()   Searched in:
    - '/home/XX/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
**********************************************************************
```

When I had the same issue at home, I could resolve it by two ways:

1. Using nltk.download(), the standard way and
2. Creating a new folder at location /home/XX/nltk_data  and just pasting the corpus directory inside it.

Now at the university I only have access to /home/XX/bin and not /home/XX directly. So is there anyway I could paste the wordnet corpus into /home/XX/bin and then somehow make nltk look for the corpus in that folder?

Answer (score 5):

Set [NLTK_DATA environment variable](http://nltk.org/data.html):

```
export NLTK_DATA=/path/to/nltk_data
```

Answer (score 0):

virtualenv is also a choice in this type of situation.